# delete comments with the user

Tags: django, django-views, django-comments

I am using the [comment library](https://github.com/danirus/django-comments-xtd). It is built on top of  django-contrib-comments

The question is, how can you make sure that when you delete a user, all comments associated with him would be deleted? I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

The [**`Comment`**--(source)](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/01f6a5a81959467ecf60fd1a47d0797e8815a649/django_comments/models.py#L16) model defined as,

```
class CommentFlag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name="comment_flags",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # rest of the fields
```

Note that, the `user` field defined with a **`on_delete=models.CASCADE`** which ensures that Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.

Ref: [`models.CASCADE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't quite understand, does this mean that comments should be deleted at the moment? What changes and where do I need to make?)